Area 2-form and index 1-form on the Hyperbolic Semiplane
I'm having some trouble in defining/deducing a natural 2-form of area in the upper-half plane model of the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^2$. Probably this is a very basic question. I set the context below.
In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard coordinates $(x,y)$, consider the differential 1-forms given by $dx,dy:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $dx(v)=a$ and $dy(v)=b$ for each $v=(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. If we consider the "index" 1-form
$$\omega = -ydx_1+xdy$$
(that is responsible for calculating the index of a closed curve that turns around the origin), then
$$dw=dx\wedge dy,$$
which is the cannonical 2-form of area in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So by the Stokes theorem, if $\Gamma\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a domain and $\partial\Gamma=\gamma$, the area $A(\Gamma)$ is just
$$A(\Gamma)=\int_{\Gamma}d\omega = \int_{\gamma}\omega.$$
I'm trying to do exactly this in the hyperbolic space. Namely, I want to find some natural 1-form on the hyperbolic space (upper hal-plane model) alike the $w$ above, taking into account the metric structure
$$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathbb{H}^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle{_{\mathbb{R}^2}},$$
and such that if $E\subset \mathbb{H}^2$ is a domain with $\partial E=\varepsilon$ (simple and positively oriented), then
$$A(E)=\int_{E}d\omega = \int_{\varepsilon}\omega.$$
I was trying something like $\omega=-dx+\frac{x}{y}dy$, which exterior derivative is $d\omega=\frac{1}{y}dx\wedge dy$, but I'm afraid I'm not aware of what is the natural 2-form of area on the upper half-plane model of the hyperbolic space.
So I guess my question is: what is the "index" 1-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{H}^2$ such that $dw$ is the 2-form of area. Any help will be very appreciated!

First, you are missing a factor of $2$ in the original $d\omega$. (Note that the form in the Euclidean plane is very non-unique.) In the hyperbolid plane, you want the area form $\dfrac{dx\wedge dy}{y^2} = d\left(\dfrac{dx}y\right)$. (This is actually the connection $1$-form $\omega_{12}$ when you work with the standard orthonormal coframe $\omega_1=dx/y$, $\omega_2=dy/y$. So it has a natural geometric meaning.)

In general, let $n\geq 2$, and consider $\Bbb{H}_n=\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\times (0,\infty)$, with the metric
\begin{align}
g&=\frac{dx_1^2+\dots+dx_{n}^n}{x_n^2}.
\end{align}
So, the natural volume form is
\begin{align}
\mu_{\Bbb{H}^n}&=\sqrt{|\det g_{ab}|}\cdot dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{n}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x_n^2}\right)^n}\cdot dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n\\
&=\frac{1}{x_n^n}\cdot dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n.
\end{align}
Now, you can say the upper half-plane has very nice topology, so by Poincare’s lemma, it is exact, or you can explicitly verify that if
\begin{align}
\omega:=\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)x_n^{n-1}}\cdot dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{n-1},
\end{align}
then we have $\mu_{\Bbb{H}^n}=d\omega$. Also, this is not the only possibility, we have that $\mu_{\Bbb{H}^n}=d\zeta$ if and only if there is some $(n-2)$-form $\alpha$ such that $\zeta=\omega+d\alpha$.
So, in the case $n=2$, this means $\mu_{\Bbb{H}^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}\,dx\wedge dy$ and $\omega=\frac{dx}{y}$ works, but like I said above, $\omega$ is not unique; we can consider $\omega+df$ for any smooth function $f$, and it will produce the same area 2-form.

Thank you very much! In fact, this last comment about choosing any $f$ probably will help me a lot. I have some integrations to perform and maybe a right choice of $f$ will help.
